# c++ compile multiple cpp files using cmakefile.txt in linux

Tags: c++, cmake

I am quite new to linux and c++.. i have couple of cpp file and cmakefile.txt in my source folder. how can i compile in ubuntu with g++ (multiple cpp files)

I have this CMakeList.txt

```
project(Test)

# link_libraries($Nest_LIBRARIES})


subdirs(
#  
  engine
  options
  ui

#  jni
  )



#build the Test library
add_library(test STATIC
  options/command_line_options.cpp
  options/options_map.cpp
  utility/timer.cpp
  utility/generics/any.cpp
  util/hdfs.cpp
  logger/logger.cpp
  logger/backtrace.cpp
   )
requires_core_deps(test)
```

INSTALL(TARGETS 
  test ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

Answer (score 0):

This is CMake ([tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html)). Some say it simplifies build process.

1. Create makefiles from CMake metafiles: `cmake . -G "Unix
   Makefiles"`
2. Run make: `make -j2 install`

Comment: i am getting an error message "could not create named generator unix make files

Comment: does it say why? try runnin it from another directory giving full path to sources instead of `.` in the command line